# Rails 4: Group Text Message Strategy - Passing Multiple Records to a Controller

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, twilio

My Rails app works by letting Users create Clients and then send or schedule text_messages using Twilio. Creating one Client and then generating one text_message record works great. The User owns Clients which owns Text_Message.

My next feature to tackle is to allow a User to choose which Clients they want to send a group text message too. I want to generate a text_message record for each Client (with the same content and scheduled_date). Saved text_messages are getting added to a Sidekiq queue.

I need some help (please) on the strategy on this. How do I implement Group_Text while keeping the code dry and continuing to generate records for the text_message table? How do I pass multiple selected clients from a form/view to a controller to create the records while using the logic from the Text_Message model? Thanks for the pointers!

## Relevant code

**schema.rb**

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141207214913) do

      # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
      enable_extension "plpgsql"

      create_table "action_plans", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "client_id"
        t.text     "description"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

      add_index "action_plans", ["client_id"], name: "index_action_plans_on_client_id", using: :btree

      create_table "clients", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "user_id"
        t.string   "first_name",    null: false
        t.string   "last_name",     null: false
        t.string   "phone",         null: false
        t.string   "salesforce_id", null: false
        t.string   "email"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.text     "contact_id"
      end

      add_index "clients", ["user_id"], name: "index_clients_on_user_id", using: :btree

      create_table "coach_emails", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "user_id"
        t.string   "email",            null: false
        t.string   "coach_firstname"
        t.string   "client_lastname"
        t.string   "client_firstname"
        t.text     "content",          null: false
        t.boolean  "sentstatus"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

      add_index "coach_emails", ["user_id"], name: "index_coach_emails_on_user_id", using: :btree

      create_table "goals", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "action_plan_id"
        t.text     "description"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

      add_index "goals", ["action_plan_id"], name: "index_goals_on_action_plan_id", using: :btree

      create_table "steps", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "goal_id"
        t.text     "description"
        t.date     "due_by"
        t.boolean  "complete",    default: false
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

      add_index "steps", ["goal_id"], name: "index_steps_on_goal_id", using: :btree

      create_table "text_messages", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "client_id"
        t.text     "content"
        t.boolean  "incoming_message"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.date     "scheduled_date"
        t.boolean  "sentstatus"
        t.integer  "step_id"
        t.string   "phone"
      end

      add_index "text_messages", ["client_id"], name: "index_text_messages_on_client_id", using: :btree

      create_table "users", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
        t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
        t.string   "reset_password_token"
        t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
        t.datetime "remember_created_at"
        t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
        t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
        t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
        t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
        t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
        t.string   "first_name"
        t.string   "last_name"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.string   "role"
        t.string   "title"
        t.string   "confirmation_token"
        t.datetime "confirmed_at"
        t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
        t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
      end

      add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
      add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

    end
```

**text_message.rb**

```
    require 'twilio-ruby'
    require 'date'

    class TextMessage < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :client, dependent: :destroy
      belongs_to :step, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :coach_emails

    before_save :grab_phone

      def grab_phone
        self.phone = phone
      end

      def send_text_message(message, phone)

        twilio_sid = ENV["TWILIO_ACCT_SID"]
        twilio_token = ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
        twilio_phone_number = ENV["TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER"]

        begin
          @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(twilio_sid, twilio_token)

          @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
            :from => "+1#{twilio_phone_number}",
            :to => phone,
            :body => message)

          rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => e
            puts e.message
        end

        if e != "400" || e != "500"
          self.sentstatus = true
        end

        self.save!
      end  
    end
```

**routes.rb**

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

    require 'sidekiq/web'

      devise_for :users, :path => '',
        :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}, 
        :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }

      authenticate :user do
        mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
      end

      resources :clients do
        resources :action_plans, shallow: true, except: [:index] 
      end

      resources :action_plans, shallow: true, only: [] do
        resources :goals, shallow: true, except: [:index]
      end

      resources :goals, shallow: true, only: [] do
        resources :steps, shallow: true, except: [:index, :destroy]
      end

      resources :steps, shallow: true, only: [] do
        resources :text_messages, shallow: true, except: [:index, :destroy]
      end

      get "text_messages/receive"
      match '/receivetext' => 'text_messages#receive', :via => :post

      resources :clients do
        collection do
          post :welcome
        end
      end

      get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

      root to: 'welcome#index'

    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I need to add to the TextMessage controller (#groupnew and #groupcreate).

## New Routes

```
get 'group_new' => 'text_messages#group_new' 
post 'group_create' => 'text_messages#group_create'
```

## Updated TextMessage Controller

```
def group_new
  @clients = current_user.clients.order(:last_name)
  @text_message = TextMessage.new 
end

def group_create
  client_hash = params[:client_id]

  client_hash.each do |client|
    @client = Client.find(client)
    content = params[:text_message][:content]

    @text_message = @client.text_messages.build(text_message_params)
    @text_message.incoming_message = false
    @text_message.sentstatus = false
    @text_message.phone = @client.phone

    if @text_message.scheduled_date == nil 
      @text_message.scheduled_date = Date.today
      # print time in Pacific time
      @text_message.scheduled_time = Time.now.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
      @text_message.send_text_message(@text_message.content, @text_message.phone)
    else
      @text_message.save 
    end
  end
  redirect_to clients_path
end
```

Group text now works :)